# Fully Resetting NLog Configuration

Tags: .net, nlog

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // 1. At this point NLog will search for most common configuration locations,
    //    as described in http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file.

    var loggerOne = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerOne");

    // 2. We set NLog configuration to null, hoping that the next time the
    // configuration is requested the whole process (1) will be repeated.

    LogManager.Configuration = null;

    // 3. NLog won't actually repeat process (1), and so logging is disabled for
    //    the following logger since the configuration is still null.

    var loggerTwo = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerTwo");
}
```

Browsing NLog's source code it is clear that this has to do with the `configLoaded` field of the underlying `LogFactory` being set at `true` at startup, and not being reset to `false` after assigning `null` to the `Configuration` property (which would, for me, make the most sense). My question is whether I am missing something in this process or if it it really the case that there's no way (without using Reflection, of course) to force NLog to reconfigure itself from scratch and repeat process `(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me ask what it is that you are trying to accomplish?  Is this more of an exercise in trying to see how NLog works?  Is there something in particular that are trying to accomplish?  If the latter, maybe there is already a sanctioned way to do what you want to do.

Having said that, I have an idea (that I have not tried) that might work.

In looking at the NLog source, it seems like you might be able to do something like this:

```
LogManager.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
```

Assigning a new LoggingConfiguration looks like it will cause the logging configuration process to be started from scratch.  I'm not sure what will happen with any loggers that might have been retrieved while the old configuration was in effect.  Will they still be valid?  Will they do anything at all?